# How do we use two composite adjectives in a row?

Tags: grammar

How do we use two composite adjectives in a row?

For example:

> We have a lot of mathematics-intensive and science-intensive courses.

Can the above be reduced to:

> We have a lot of mathematics and science-intensive courses.

I am not sure, but it doesn't seem like it's allowed by the rules of English grammar, because we cannot imply the use of "-intensive"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run into a situation like this, I do what Chicago Manual of Style (17th ed.) does.

Examples from CMoS (7.89: Hyphenation guide):

> *five- or ten-minute intervals* (= five-minute or ten-minute intervals)
>   *a group of ten- and eleven-year-olds* (= ten-year-olds and eleven-year-olds)

Based on those examples, I would write your sentence this way:

> We have a lot of mathematics- and science-intensive courses.

This style is fairly common though and not specific to CMoS.